# Excel VBA Hide different columns depending on different cell values in another sheet, in real time

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a workbook with 5 sheets: Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3, Sheet4, Sheet5. The first sheet: "Sheet" has a cell: "C3" with a drop down menu with 4 different options: Opt1, Opt2, Opt3, Opt4. 
Depending on what is selected in this drop down menu, I'd like different columns to be hidden in the various sheets - in real time. And if nothing is entered, I'd like no columns hidden.

I've entered the below code which partly works but I think there's an issue because I've selected overlapping columns to hide - not completely sure.

Additionally, I'd like to work in hiding particular rows as well as the column below, depending on what different option you select in the drop down menu.

Also, I'll replicate hiding the same columns across all Sheets1-5.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("C3").Value = "Opt1" Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("G:L").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("N:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Else
        Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("G:L").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("N:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If  

    If Range("C3").Value = "Opt2" Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("B:F").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("N:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Else
        Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("B:F").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("N:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If

    If Range("C3").Value = "Opt3" Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("B:M").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Else
        Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("B:M").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If

    If Range("C3").Value = "Opt4" Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("B:AB").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Else
        Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("B:AB").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you start will all columns in range being unhidden at start of sub ( Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("B:AB").EntireColumn.Hidden = False) and then add in only the if  (not the else) parts of your code afterwards? This will mean that only the specified columns against the test condition will be hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rewritten your code to make it easy to read and edit. My goal was to make the code as short as possible. I changed your if statement into a Select Case. It's more elegant and I think it's faster, but don't take my word for it.

**The problem** that had to be tackled was that if I select *Opt1* and then select *Opt2*, the columns from *Opt1* would still be hidden. So before the code hides anything, it automatically unhides all the columns in the range B:AB.

I added the `Case Else` to unhide all columns if you entered anything but Opt1, Opt2, Opt3 or Opt4. This could easily be changed into a MsgBox that warns the user that the entered value is incorrect. *You can remove this line if you have limited the choice for the users already.*

**The Code:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ' Unhide Columns
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B:AB").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

    Select Case Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C3").Value

        Case "Opt1"
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("G:L,N:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

        Case "Opt2"
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B:F,N:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

        Case "Opt3"
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B:M").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

        Case "Opt4"
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B:AB").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

        ' If anything else is entered, the columns will be unhidden.
        Case Else
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B:AB").EntireColumn.Hidden = False

    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help EliasWick!

Answer (score 1):

Following on from my comment. You can define the entire range of columns as a variable e.g. entireRange and set this to unhidden at the start of each worksheet change.

Add fully qualified references to the ranges i.e. ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") or ws (as a variable shown below).

As everything is unhidden at start Else is not needed for each If statement. This is probably where confusion arises.

Change to a Select case statement as you are testing the value of a single cell against different expected values.

Combine your separate line column ranges that you are hiding into one line statements e.g.

```
 Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("G:L").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
 Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("N:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

Becomes:

```
 ws.Range("G:L,N:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

You code would then look like the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim entireRange As Range
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set entireRange = ws.Columns("B:AB")

    entireRange.EntireColumn.Hidden = False

    Select Case ws.Range("C3") 'Test the value of C3

      Case "Opt1"
          ws.Range("G:L,N:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

      Case "Opt2"
          ws.Range("B:F,N:T").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

      Case "Opt3"
          ws.Range("B:M").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

      Case "Opt4"
          entireRange.Hidden = True

    End Select
End Sub
```

This will be easier to debug in terms of where things are being hidden or unhidden.

Comment: Thankyou so much QHarr! I ended up using the logic of your code. I set each Sheet as a separate ws1, ws2 etc then defined the range for each one. Thanks for the help!! :)